# Window Snapping doesn't work despite being turned on

Tags: windows-10, aero-snap, windows-snap-assist

In the Windows 10 settings app, all Window snapping options are turned on. But windows don't change size when moving them to the edge of the screen.

How can this be debugged?

Which registry keys affect this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Set Snap ON and select the three settings below. Restart the computer.

Now, as you move the App to the side, keep moving it until you see the faint vertical line and it will snap to the side.

I tested this well before posting.

Comment: What you're describing is how it's supposed to work. But in my case I did all this and apps don't snap to the side.